# postgres running only one query per core

Tags: postgresql

I have found out that one core of a CPU is running only one query at a time. And other queries are queued up. Is it a limitation of postgres?

I have a 4 core CPU for postgres and I have submitted 6 queries parallely in 6 different sessions of psql. But I am seeing only 1 query per CPU and the remaining queries are queued. I am not sure why is it happening. Do you have any special scheduler for postgres? I can see that CPU has been shared with other non postgres processes but postgres processes are not sharing any CPU within a core. The following is the process states.

> lms       2868  2209 98 07:20 ?        00:12:30 postgres: lms
>   controller [local] SELECT
>
> lms       2869  2209 98 07:20 ?        00:12:30 postgres: lms
>   controller [local] SELECT
>
> lms       2870  2209  0 07:20 ?        00:00:00 postgres: lms
>   controller [local] SELECT
>
> lms       2871  2209  0 07:20 ?        00:00:00 postgres: lms
>   controller [local] SELECT
>
> lms       2872  2209  0 07:20 ?        00:00:00 postgres: lms
>   controller [local] SELECT
>
> lms       2873  2209 98 07:20 ?        00:12:30 postgres: lms
>   controller [local] SELECT

If you see above, three Select queries have been queued. They are acquiring CPU only when there is a core without any postgres query running on it. The CPU utilization time is 0 while the other queries reached 12m 30 sec.

I know the postgres limitation of one query using only one core. But is there any limitation of one CPU running only one query at a time?

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks and regards,

Vineel.

Comment: What query are you running ? It might be some lock issue.